# How to generate the excel file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory

I need to generate an excel file in Azure Data Factory and save it in a blob storage. I know that Sink to Excel file is not available. I would like to create an Azure Function in PowerShell to achieve this but I don't know how to go about it.